# How to convert a chart to a dataset/csv

Tags: dataframe, powerpoint

does anybody know a reliable way to convert charts to a dataset (csv, pandas, ...)? I only have the png of the chart below but need the dataset to plot the chart on my own.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a solution, but I guess as a first step you can put a grid on top of the chart, maybe in 2% steps. Then you can get an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this web based tool to extract numerical data from plot images:  [WebPlotDigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd). Tool allows you to upload images with plots/graphs, select data points of interest and download them into csv format.

You could also install it on your desktop: [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/download.html)